# About sql server rules

Tags: sql-server, constraints, rules

How can I correct this syntax , create rule r1 as @ f <1000 ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [CHECK constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188064.aspx) instead because CREATE RULE is deprecated?

Seriously, I've not used a rule since the 90s

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the space between the @ and f:

```
create rule r1 as @f < 1000
```

You should also consider using a [check constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) instead, as Microsoft have indicated that rules will be removed from future versions of SQL Server